# linux scripted git pull error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission Denied

Tags: linux, git, bash

Need a little help scripting a git pull.

We have an intranet server that we are trying to script a git pull to, and I'm running into a permission issue.

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

We've setup a user account on the server, cloned the project to that account, chmod 775 -R the directory tree, and setup the ssh key so there is no password prompt.

The script looks like so:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo /bin/su - gitrepouser
cd /some/directory/for/git && git pull
```

When I run the script as another user, it runs the sudo command, and stops, after typing exit and I get the error message.

This script will be called by our batch process on a 10 minute interval, pulling any production changes down from BitBucket.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make the user the owner of the folder

```
chown gitrepouser -Rf /some/directory/for/git
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `su` starts its own shell; the second command isn't executed in that shell, but in the original one. You can demonstrate this by running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
su
whoami
```

Unless you're already root when you run it, it won't output `root`.

The solution is to use `su`'s `-c` switch:

```
sudo /bin/su -c "cd /some/directory/for/git && git pull" - gitrepouser
```

Comment: I tried this, and have to wait for our admin to give me permissions to run the command.